# What are the rules for how Ruby figures out if a variable is local or a getter method, especially regarding dynamically created variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just solved a bug that was caused by variables created by `store_accessor` needing `self`

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord

  store_accessor :jsonb_column, :bar

  def some_method
    if name && bar # name is column in DB
      # does cool stuff
    end
  end

end

(byebug) $ name     #=> "Joey Joe Jo Shabbado"
(byebug) $ bar      #=> nil
(byebug) $ self.bar #=> "1"
```

So, how do you know when you need `self`?

Comment: It could be the scope in which byebug is searching for local variables or methods is different from the scope in which the method exists, or possibly that you have a pre-existing `bar` variable fro some reason.

Comment: Very interesting!  Where did you set `bar`?  Was it already persisted?

Comment: @tadman It wasn't just in byebug, changing it to `self.bar` in `some_method` was what fixed my code. Byebug is just where I figured it out so I kept that as the example.
@SteveTurczyn I'm not sure if it was persisted, some of my records were created before the change, and one during I lost track of which was which. But I think `bar` was added after initializing and before saving, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This could be a quirk of how `store_accessor` defines methods.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal test case that demonstrates the issue? I'm having trouble actually reproducing this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. In your title, you ask about "instant" variables. I have no idea what that is, but assuming, you actually mean "instance" variables, the distinction is easy: local variables start with a lowercase letter or underscore, instance variables start with `@`, and it doesn't matter whether they were dynamically created. But there are no instance variables in your code anywhere, so why does it matter how Ruby figures out the difference?

Comment: @JohnFeminella this is a faithful reproduction of the bug that was in my code, I just changed the names. And I think if I knew what else was different that could help you reproduce I would already know my answer.
JörgWMittag I changed the title from "instant" variable to getter method, but I think everyone knew what I meant.

Comment: When JohnFeminella says "minimal test case", I believe he means, "give me the exact steps I need to reproduce your problem, assuming I *only* have a recent ruby interpreter with basic tools like bundler." Without this, we have no reliable way to help you. Example of missing information: what is `ApplicationRecord` and how do we install it? Either provide its code, or a `Gemfile` with the exact version you're using.